# will a 100GB database with large tables on MSSQL 2008 server run on a 3GB RAM system?

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory, database-administration

This will be only for testing and developing.
I have a 100 GB DB I am working on and need a sanbox envorinment.
The only hardware I have is a desktop with 3GB and 32bit.
I am able to install SQL 2008 Ent 32-bit (trial) on XP with no issues.
Will there be any problems starting the service once I get the large DB restored?

Comment: Why not install a Server 2008r2 trial also and add more ram?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it will *run*.

How fast however depends on your working data set. 3GB RAM (and about 1GB used for the OS) is not much to run SQL on.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for a test environment, you might as well just try it out and see if it works to your satisfaction. No amount of speculation will give you as good of an answer as actually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Our current production system is running a 250 GB on average filesize database for a web application with no signs of performance issues.   Our setup is a SQL 2005 Workgroup running on 2003 SBS with 3.25 GB RAM

We are in the process of upgrading to SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 with 32 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be able to restore the database? Yes.
Will the database be accessible so that you can run queries against it? Yes.
Will the performance suck? Probably

The answer to that last one really depends on how much data you need to load into memory.  Given that you've only got 3 Gigs of RAM installed, you've probably got about 1 Gig of memory for SQL Server to use.  So if your testing only needs a few rows of data, then everything will be just fine.  However if your testing needs to run queries over all of the data then performance will be horrible as you'll be thrashing the disks.